# Postgres determine size of all blobs

Tags: postgresql, blob

hi i'm trying to find the size of all blobs. I always used this

```
SELECT sum(pg_column_size(pg_largeobject)) lob_size FROM pg_largeobject
```

but while my database is growing ~40GB this takes several hours and loads the cpu too much.

is there any more efficent way?

Comment: Isn't `pg_table_size('pg_largeobject')` good enough?

Comment: seems good, but why do they give different results? SELECT pg_table_size('pg_largeobject'), sum(pg_column_size(pg_largeobject)) lob_size FROM pg_largeobject 750MB/545MB

Comment: `pg_table_size` includes the padding between rows, the dead rows, row headers... that's the real size on disk.

Comment: ok, then pleas write this as answer so i can accept it

Answer (score 2):

Some of the functions mentioned in [Database Object Management Functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBOBJECT) give an immediate result for the entire table.

I'd suggest `pg_table_size(regclass)` which is defined as:

> Disk space used by the specified table, excluding indexes (but
>   including TOAST, free space map, and visibility map)

It differs from `sum(pg_column_size(tablename)) FROM tablename` because it counts entire pages, so that includes the padding between the rows, the dead rows (updated or deleted and not reused), and the row headers.